# How to replace all non-letters in a given string s by symbol '*'

Tags: java

For example
Input

> Hello 1/(¤

Output should be

```
Hello ****
```

Comment: Peter, as you might have noticed from the answers (and comments!) below, it would help if you'd clarify what characters you want to keep. Only the ranges `a..z` and `A..Z` or all letters? If it's the latter, Fabian's answer is the proper one, or else zneak or Aly's answers will do.

Answer (score 7):

To make your regular expression work with international alphabets (e.g. to treat letters with diacritics as letters too, like `ä`, `à`, etc.), you should use the unicode-aware expression for a non-letter character:

```
"Héllö 1/(¤".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]", "*");
```

Comment: It seems Peter doesn't want the space character(s) to be replaced, in which case you ought to add `\\s` to your negated class.

Comment: -1: I believe that regular expressions are not a part of the askers skill set.  This solution will hence be unmaintainable.

Comment: Well Thorbjørn, feel free to provide another answer. One that will be "more maintainable" in your opinion. B.t.w., I don't see how a regex like the one proposed would be unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Hello 1/(¤".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "*")
```

Comment: He wants to collapse the `*`'s into a single `*`

Comment: No he doesn't, that was markdown/html formatting glitch.  I edited the question so you can see text easier.

Comment: Won't this regex also replace the whitespace?

Comment: What about characters like `é`?